# How to use grep commend with variable

Tags: linux, grep

How can i use grep commend with variable ?

- I stored ' Feb 1 ' (future it will be changeable) to variable 'date'.
- Now i want to grep this variable 'date', How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
DATE='Feb 1'
grep "$DATE" [filename]
```

You need to put quotes around it because of the space in your variable.

Comment: Shells don't like spaces around the `=`.

Comment: Good point, corrected :)